# Kinetic energy vs Kinetic Energy scenario in a collision, mechanical energy used for work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics, work

Most collisions have Kinetic energy conserved or in the case of inelastic collisions energy is lost into other forms.

Though the equation of "TMEi + Wnc =TMEf" is true

however, what if two unequal masses such as a ball that weights .15 kg's and a cart that weights 35kg..

IF the ball is coming from the left, with 600 Joules of KE and from the right the cart has 300 Joules, the cart has superior momentum but the ball has superior KE.

Lets say that they lost some energy to other forms, 600 joule ball has 120 Joules left and the cart has 60 Joules lets say.

IF the KE remains to do work, the ball should stop the cart in a VERY short distance (like 0.00001 meters) and then with the remaining energy will push the cart back.

Ignore momentum, its irrelevant in this situation as there is a EXTERNAL force or a non-conservative force doing non-conservative work (Wnc).

So, we could say TMEi ball + (-TMEi cart) = TMEf

Now, if we take this external force...This KE vs KE scenario could be true and that the superior KE of ball stopped the less KE of cart, doing work on the cart that has superior momentum and mass.

A scenario like this in real life is with cars and blowing wind. Mechanical energy of wind in the form of KE can do work, stopping a car and blowing it backwards.

MY question is asking if this correct and that if energy remains to do non-conservative work, it can do so, as mechanical energy is the ability to do work.